# Open ID, Storing card details, and PCI compliance

Tags: pci-dss, openid

If you store payment card details for a user, and you have a 'Login via openID' which includes services like Google and Facebook, is this allowed under PCI Compliance? Or do you need your own distinct openID login server?

Comment: Is the Open ID authentication being used to access the card holder data?

Comment: it wouldn't be to access the data, but to use it for future purchases.

Comment: see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1845/is-facebook-connect-or-twitter-oauth-pci-compliant?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

For use by consumers, I believe you should be ok, but for use by employee's you'd potentially run afoul of PCI-DSS requirement 8.5.  OpenID provides an authentication mechanism independent of data and validates a user matches with the unique ID assigned to the user within your system.  For non-consumer users there are additional requirements for password complexity and changes that might not be enforced by a third party OpenID system, however for the consumer users (whose information is being protected), it seems to be allowable to let them use an OpenID to authenticate.